# Transforming an equation to a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, problem-solving, transformation

We have seen transforming a differential equation to a system of equations.
I ask about the reverse procedure, specifically transforming an equation to a differential equation. Here I have an equation (assume a polynomial  $ p(x)$ of degree n with all roots in real domain) that is structured in a specific way so can be rewritten as a differential equation, for example a first order:
$$ p(x) := u(x) + \alpha u'(x) \tag{*}\label{*}  $$
and to find the roots $p(x) = 0 \to u(x) + \alpha u'(x) = 0$: 
$$ ln (u) = -x/\alpha + c  \to u(x) = e^{(-x/\alpha)+c}  \tag{**}\label{**} $$
The goal is to numerically solve the and analyze the simpler $(**)$ equation (assume $u(x)$ is more well behaved and informative than $p(x)$).

My questions are:

- Is this strategy valid and does it recovers all real roots of the original equation (polynomial)?
- If so, how should I chose the constant c ?
- Does this approach obscures root multiplicities, if there is any?
- Is there any publication (book, paper, course note, ...) that addresses such approach in a more general sense

Thanks

Comment: $p(x) := u(x) + \alpha u'(x) = 0$. Have you just defined $p(x)$ to be the zero polynomial here?

Comment: @Physicist137 i think the intent is to have $p(x)$ defined as the solution to the equation on the RHS of $:=$

Comment: We know from the examples of DEs with constant coefficients, Cauchy-Euler equations and Laplace transforms the utility of using the algebra of polynomial and rational expressions in solving DEs and initial value problems. Does there exist a way of transforming polynomial equations into differential equations in such a way that it is easier to solve the differential equation than it is to solve the polynomial equation? It is an interesting question which begs for an example.

Comment: How does you transform a differential equation to a system of equations? Is it using some transform?

Comment: Thanks @JohnWaylandBales for raising such valuable question. The way to see (or transform) polynomial equation to simple differential equation, is surely challenging.  In my case, I can see the DE in my polynomial, and want to know about the details and limitations of the approach. As an example assume a $u(x)$ be a Wilkinson type polynomial of lower degree i.e. $ n=3 , u(x) = (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$ and $ p(x) = u(x) + \alpha (3x^2 -12x+11)$, can I use $u(x) = e^{(-x/\alpha)+c}$ construct and find all roots in any condition?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. You have a polynomial $p(x) = u(x) + \alpha u'(x)$. There are two cases to consider (1) This is the zero polynomial (2) This is not the zero polynomial. Lets explore (1).

Lets just assume your polynomial is over $\mathbb{R}$ for simplicity. We can assume a general field, however, then the differential equation would have to find solutions over that field as well. If $p$ is the zero polynomial, then:
$$
p(x) = 0, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}\implies u(x) + \alpha u'(x) = 0, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}
$$

Then, your equation with a derivative **is zero** for all values of $x$. Thus, it is a differential equation, then you have its solution: $u(x) = Ae^{-x/\alpha}$ for some $A\in\mathbb{R}$. Since $p(0) = 0$ then $A = 0$, then a solution to the differential equation exists: $u(x) = 0$. Which is the zero polynomial. Then, $p(x) = u(x) + \alpha u'(x) = 0$, as expected.

---

Now we will see why it won't work with case (2). Have a nonzero polynomial $p(x)$ and define it to be $p(x) = u(x) + \alpha u'(x)$ for some function $u$ (which turns out to be polynomials as well. If you make $p(x) = 0$, then you are not saying this is the zero polynomial, you are saying you want $x_k$ such that $p(x_k) = 0$. That is, you wanna solve by finding $x_k$ such that $
u(x_k) + \alpha u'(x_k) = 0$. This **is not a differential equation**. You can only construct the solution if and only if:
$$
u(x) = Ae^{x/\alpha} \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad u(x) + \alpha u'(x) = 0,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}
$$

Which is only true if $p(x)$ is the zero polynomial.

---

I am not saying that: What you asked is impossible. I am saying that it cannot be done in the way you suggested. There might exist a way of doing so. And one can just look at the reverse procedure: How to transform an ODE into a polynomial? The answer is simple: Transforms. Laplace transform, Fourier transform, etc. Then how to transform a polynomial into ODE? The key might be inverse laplace transform, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Physicist137 for your answer. First, I do not consider the zero polynomial. Since I start with a non zero polynomial. Later I figure out that I can divide the polynomial to two part so that one part is the derivative of the second part. My goal is to get some extra information about roots of original polynomial from the observed structure. The second part of your answer is very helpful. Yes, $u(x_k) +\alpha u'(x_k) = 0$ is only valid in n distinct point, thus not a differential equation.

Comment: But the question is how I can benefit from that $u(x) + \alpha u'(x)$ structure and come up with some understanding about the behavior of the roots of $p(x)$. Regarding transforms, I think using Laplace transform and inverse of it, if analytically derivable, returns back us to the original polynomial $p(x)$ which is not desired. Can you be more specific? Assume $p(x)$ is sum of a Wilkinson polynomial and it's weighted derivative. Thanks again.

Comment: I am still confused why I cannot find proper literature for the the kinds of my problem. I restate again: having a function (or polynomial) with a built in structure of $p_1(x) = u(x) + \alpha u'(x)$ or $p_2(x) = u(x) + \alpha u'(x) + \beta u''(x)$, how one can analyze the behavior of those polynomials especially around zero, benefiting their differential structure? Which category of mathematics addresses this type of questions? I'll appreciate if anyone guides me to a proper link, if there is any.

Comment: @Henry Well... I don't see anyway. If $p(x) = u(x) + \alpha u'(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $u(x)$ is a polynomial, and $u(x) + \alpha u'(x)$ is the same polynomial you try to find roots. You are summing $u$ and $u'$. So, a sum don't quite help when dealing with roots... I don't think there is a way to benefit from the fact a derivative is there.

Comment: my intuition disagrees :) That structure is an extra information added. In frequency domain it means $P(s) = (1+\alpha s) U(s)$, which $(1+\alpha s)$ filters $U(s)$, I think I can comprehend that as an $\alpha \pi /2 $ phase addition to frequency content of $u(s)$, I don't know how I can map this to zero crossings of the time domain polynomials $p(x) .vs. u(x)$.